Execute a script when powering off, but not when rebooting (using systemd)
I'm working on scripts to power the TV connected to my Mac (running Linux) on and off.  These scripts make use of the cec-ctl util (part of video4l), which control the CEC pin of the HDMI output.
The main goal is to switch the TV off on shutdown (but not when rebooting).
So, how can I setup a systemd service/unit to execute a script as the last thing before powering off, but not when rebooting?

You've not yet indicated that Ubuntu product/release you're asking about, is this Ubuntu Core? Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Desktop? and importantly what release of that unstated product.
